# Align/Wrap images around div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alignment

What I'm trying to achieve is a page with a div centered in the middle of the screen (720x360).  This is done with jQuery using:

```
$(window).height()
```

and:

```
$(window).width()
```

which work perfectly.

The next part is getting 180x180 images to fit around that middle div.  These will fill the screen + beyond.

I'm stuck on how to get these to align that way and I couldn't find a live example of anyone doing the same thing.

So, is this even possible?

Comment: you can write a css class for the design and let your image inherit it.Try "getattribute" in jquery

Comment: Can't you position the images with the same technique that put the div in the middle but with appropriately offset coordinates? Perhaps you could show what you've got so far (html, css and JS).

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">

#main {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto; /* This is make div into center of screen*/
    width: 720px;
    height: 360px;
    background: #ccc; /* Just for visibility */
    position: relative; /* As we want to make other div into center of this */
}

#content {
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 36.36%; /* You can calculate using math */
    /*
        Total Width - Width
        So you will get end point now minus half
        Width / 2 = 90
        Then 720 - 180 = 540
        And now your box will point to end but you need to divide
        half of width again 90/2 = 45
        Result is : 
        180/2/2 = 45
        720-180-45 = 495
        180/495*100 = 36.36
        So this is your width position.
    * */
    top: 25%;
    /*
    Same for height but as you can see it's 25% of your value and very easy
    * */
    background: red;
}


    </style>
    <div id="main">
   <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
```